# kill a thread after resume the main activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, save, kill, onresume

I have this problem in android. i have a main activity who calls a thread with this

```
   Runnable work = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        while (kill) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                connect();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


    }
};
```

kill its a public boolean in MainActivity.
what can i do to save the thread so when i resume the activity i still can kill the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to do something closer to what [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821423/background-task-progress-dialog-orientation-change-is-there-any-100-working) proposes.

However, if you really want to keep doing it in a `Thread`, then I suggest you extend a new class from `Thread` and add a method called `killMe()`. This will modify the (now *private*) boolean `kill` flag. Then, in your `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` you can return this `Thread` and you can retrieve it again in `onResume`. If you return and activity has not been killed, then it's fine, you can just call `killMe()` on the existing `Thread`.

Example:

```
 @Override
  public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return thread;
  }
```

Comment: ok i tried with thread thing, but now i cannot save the thread to loaded on the resume :S

Comment: Hmmm how about some more info? What didn't work, specifically?

Comment: i dont know why onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() doesnt execute :S, can you giveme and example?

Comment: I've updated the answer with a sample, but, *when* are you expecting it to execute? It will only execute if the activity is killed (e.g. orientation change). Otherwise, it's not necessary to retain/restore.

Comment: i want execute the save when i press the back button and return to android apps menu, and when i click again on the application icon restores the application including the running thread. 
o there is another way to execute a single main activity that keeps the threads?
btw thanks for all the help :D

Comment: Ah see, the back button doesn't "sleep" the activity, it plain kills it, so this won't work, unless you override the `onBackPressed` behavior. The back button should kill your thread as well.

Comment: and how i do to sleep the activity??. and wake it when i press the application icon??

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to kill the thread in the resume?

Why not start the thread in the resume part, then put in a finally block to handle the fact that the `connect()` is interrupted, and then when it starts again you just need to reconnect and do the operation.

In the case of mobile devices, your best bet is to checkmark in some persistent storage where you are, so that if you are interrupted you can continue when the `Activity` is started again.

You have a high possibility of being interrupted so design for it.

The thread may be killed off by the OS so there is nothing to save and kill later.

If you really need to do something like this then start a `RemoteService` as that will run in a different process than your `Activity` and is more likely to stay around.

You may want to look at this question:

[Android Remote Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910625/android-remote-service)

Comment: i need the thread to run in background on the phone, so when the user return to the application(activity) can kill the thread just pressing a button.